# How to properly iterate through list key, value pairs in apache freemarker?

Tags: json, freemarker

I have an API that returns a JSON object containing multiple field,value pairs as string (shown below):

```
"additionalData": "{\"Description  \":\"sdfghjkl\",\"Date Occured\":\"2021-05-27T00:00:00.000Z\",\"Date Discovered\":\"2021-05-28T00:00:00.000Z\",\"Preferred Communication (Email or Phone)\":\"desi.swetz@gmail.com\"}"
```

I need to loop through this parameter (additionalData) to fetch the values in apache freemarker and pass it into individual json variables to do an HTTP post to another API. I have tried to split this into a list and access the key, value pairs as follows:

```
<#assign m = (step.http_1.additionalData)?eval>
   <#list m?keys as key>
       <#if key == "Description  ">
           <#assign Ticket_Id_Val = "${m[key]}">
          {
            "Desc":  "${Ticket_Id_Val}"
          }
       </#if>
       <#if key == "Date Occured">
           <#assign DO_Id_Val = "${m[key]}">
          {
            "DO": ${DO_Id_Val}
          }
      </#if>
       <#if key == "Date Discovered">
           <#assign DD_Id_Val = "${m[key]}">
          {
            "DD":  ${DD_Id_Val}
          }
        </#if>
       <#if key =="Preferred Communication (Email or Phone)">
           <#assign PC_Id_Val = "${m[key]}">
          {
            "PC": "${PC_Id_Val}"
          }
       </#if>
    </#list>
```

However, I found while debugging that the "DO", "DD", "PC" values are not being passed to the webhook successfully, only the "Desc" value, because we are not stepping into the other, <#if> conditions.

[image: Webhook result]

I'm either not looping through all the key pairs or have not split the additionalData correctly into a list, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: It should work, so check what actual keys you get in the loop by printing them. BTW, would be nicer with `#list m as key, value`. Also use `#elseif` for mutually exclusive conditions. Also it's safer to use `?eval_json` (since 2.3.31). Also for re-printing strings you should use `?json_string`.

Comment: I see there are some random spaces in the keys too, like `"Description  "`. I would `?trim` the key before the comparisons.